# How do i match something based on the number of strings?

Tags: c#, .net

How can i match how many times a 17 digit number appears in abunch of strings and then use them? The language is c#/.net

Comment: Try to do it, if you can't then post the code you tried and we'll help you

Comment: Show us some example code of what you have done so far, this does not match Stack Overflow's policy in asking questions.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `abunch` collection object

Comment: "and then use them"? Do you want to "use" all those occurences? Do you need the number of occurences or what?

Comment: i want to put the strings in a grid view but thats another question.

Comment: Is it a specific 17-digit number, or just any occurance of 17 digits?

Comment: any that answer is working now im going to do some reading about data grid view thank you and sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a simple Regex, But you should really read some MSDN articles before you try to "use them"

```
 // Match a Regex and Do Stuff
        public void showMatch(string input, string expr)
        {
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, expr); 
            int num = 0;  
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                string tm = m.ToString();
                num++;
                if (num == 1)
                {
                    // Do Stuff if 1 match.
                }
                if (num == 2)
                {
                    // Do Stuff if 2 matches.
                }
            }
       }


            // showMatch(input, @"(?:[0-9]+){17}");
```

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.100).aspx)